# Swift app - huge difference in FPS on iPhone vs iPad in Debug navigator

Tags: ios, iphone, performance, ipad, frame-rate

The title pretty much sums it up.  Are there any obvious reasons that an app's frames per second would be significantly lower on an iPad vs on an iPhone?

The iPhone is a 6s (purchased in November 2015) and the iPad is 4th generation (borrowed from a friend but the model was discontinued in October 2014).

I'm having the issue in all view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you are going to solve this is by using Instruments in XCode to track down the reason. Anything else is guessing. There are several WWDC videos to get you started. Start with this year's conference, they had an example of low FPS issue. The trick is not to compare the two hardware platforms but rather solving your FPS issue on the lowest performing hardware platform and then propagating up the changes to the better-performing ones.